# Case statement giving both values (the one in "then" and in "else" together) in Bigquery. What is wrong?

Tags: google-bigquery, case-when, nested-if

I want to create a flag in **Bigquery** which will return 1 when true and 0 when false. The statement works fine when it has to return the "else" value which is 0. However, when it satisfies the condition, it returns two rows with both 1 and 0 in them. Why is this happening?

Below is the code used:

```
table AS(
  SELECT
    id,
    month,
    ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) AS value
    FROM (SELECT id, extract(month FROM date) AS month,
   (32 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), MONTH), INTERVAL 31 DAY))) AS month_days,
    sum(text_sent) AS text
    FROM table1
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2020-06-30 00:00:00 UTC'
    GROUP BY 1,2,3)),
    
table_flag AS(
SELECT
id,
CASE
WHEN month = 1 AND value > 100 THEN 1
WHEN month = 2 AND value > 150 THEN 1
WHEN month = 3 AND value > 130 THEN 1
WHEN month = 4 AND value > 200 THEN 1
WHEN month = 5 AND value > 235 THEN 1
WHEN month = 6 AND value > 125 THEN 1
WHEN month = 7 AND value > 324 THEN 1
WHEN month = 8 AND value > 160 THEN 1
WHEN month = 9 AND value > 350 THEN 1
WHEN month = 10 AND value > 80 THEN 1
WHEN month = 11 AND value > 245 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS value_flag
FROM
table)

SELECT
  t.id,
  t.value,
  t.month,
  tf.value_flag
  FROM
  table t
 LEFT JOIN
  table_flag tf
  ON
  t.id = tf.id
  WHERE t.id IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
   ORDER BY 1
```

I have also tried nested IF, but that doesn't work either:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(id),
(IF((month = 1 AND value > 100), 1,
(IF((month = 2 AND value > 150), 1,
(IF((month = 3 AND value > 130), 1,
(IF((month = 4 AND value > 200), 1,
(IF((month = 5 AND value > 235), 1,
(IF((month = 6 AND value > 125), 1,
(IF((month = 7 AND value > 324), 1,
(IF((month = 8 AND value > 160), 1,
(IF((month = 9 AND value > 350), 1,
(IF((month = 10 AND value > 80), 1,
(IF((month = 11 AND value > 245), 1,0))))))))))))))))))))))
AS value_flag
FROM table)
```

This is how the output looks right now (This is NOT what I want):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjpsA.png)

The output is completely wrong. Please suggest alternate method (if any) to do it.

P.S.: This is my first question here, please let me know if any other information is needed. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `table` and `table_flag` has several rows with identical `id`. BigQuery for each row in `table` finds several rows in `table_flag`. To remove duplicates we could add `month` to `table_flag` and to the `ON` clause. But we actually do not need the last `LEFT JOIN`. Try this:

```
WITH table AS(
  SELECT
    id,
    month,
    ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) AS value
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      id, 
      extract(month FROM date) AS month,
      (32 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), MONTH), INTERVAL 31 DAY))) AS month_days,
      sum(text_sent) AS text
    FROM table1
    WHERE 
      date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2020-06-30 00:00:00 UTC'
      AND id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 1,2,3
  )
)
SELECT
  id,
  value,
  month,
  CASE
    WHEN month = 1 AND value > 100 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 2 AND value > 150 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 3 AND value > 130 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 4 AND value > 200 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 5 AND value > 235 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 6 AND value > 125 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 7 AND value > 324 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 8 AND value > 160 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 9 AND value > 350 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 10 AND value > 80 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 11 AND value > 245 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS value_flag
FROM table
ORDER BY 1
```

or this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  month,
  ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) AS value,
  CASE
    WHEN month = 1 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 100 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 2 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 150 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 3 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 130 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 4 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 200 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 5 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 235 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 6 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 125 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 7 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 324 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 8 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 160 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 9 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 350 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 10 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 80 THEN 1
    WHEN month = 11 AND ROUND((text/(month_days/7)), 2) > 245 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS value_flag
FROM (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    extract(month FROM date) AS month,
    (32 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), MONTH), INTERVAL 31 DAY))) AS month_days,
    sum(text_sent) AS text
  FROM table1
  WHERE 
    date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00 UTC' AND '2020-06-30 00:00:00 UTC'
    AND id IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
)
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: I have edited my question, Please have a look!

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: That worked! I had the join because I had one more table to add in this and that's probably what was causing the issue. Thanks a ton for the help!